# Php Youtube Grabber Script HTTPS SSL Not Work

Tags: php, https, youtube

Please help anyone my php youtube grabber site https://mymovies24.in not working HTTPS all video displaying page but HTTPS working other page example mymovies24.in/category , mymovies24.in/contact-us etc

Please any solution plz

Answer (score 1):

Youtube thumbnail URLs are http, not https, therefore web browsers consider your pages as non secure, because of mixed content (http + https). Update all your pages' resources to be https, no exception.

Comment: @SouravSarkar: Don’t forget to mark good answers as solutions. (And to upvote them once your own reputation is high enough to enable voting.)