# Grab part a youtube link from a site in php

Tags: php

I need a to grab the youtube line `//www.youtube.com/embed/AMUHafKH0oY?wmode=opaque` the ID `AMUHafKH0oY` is ever changing and i need it to automatically pull from that line ... off this page `http://www.sequesteraccess.com/livefeed` But it keeps grabbing from the first youtube video on the page instead so any advice on how to accomplish this? Any advice would be great thanks in advance!

Here is what i have tried so far

```
<?php
    function getURL($u){
        $ops = array(
          'http'=>array(
            'method'=>"GET",
            'header'=>"Accept: text/html\r\n" .
                      "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0\r\n"
          )
        );
        $co = stream_context_create($ops);
        $r = file_get_contents('http://' . $u, false, $co);
        return $r != false ? $r : "";

    }
    function GetStringBetween($string, $start, $finish){
        $string = " ".$string;
        $position = strpos($string, $start);
        if ($position == 0) return "";
        $position += strlen($start);
        $length = strpos($string, $finish, $position) - $position;
        return substr($string, $position, $length);
    }
    $grab = file_get_contents('http://www.sequesteraccess.com/livefeed'); 
    $stream = GetStringBetween($grab, 'YOU ARE NEW TO SEQUE...&quot;&#125;,&quot;hSize&quot;:null,&quot;floatDir&quot;:null,&quot;html&quot;:&quot;&lt;iframe src=\&quot;//', '&amp');
?>
<?=$stream?>
```

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412467/how-to-embed-youtube-videos-in-php

Comment: GetStringBetween should utilise domdocument / xpath instead of strpos, that's more prone to breaking then using regex

Comment: huh? im so confused sorry im new to php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Php Youtube Grabber Script HTTPS SSL Not Work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46740080/php-youtube-grabber-script-https-ssl-not-work)

Comment: No im trying to grab a line from the page source of that URL more then a youtube itself